# JsonMappingException while loading yaml Kafka configuration via Fabric8io kubernetes-client

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I have a problem with fabric8io [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) using.

What i want: Creating Kafka cluster with Strimzi operator in Kubernetes.
If i do all steps from [Strimzi quickstart guide](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/quickstart.html) with CLI and kubectl it's all good.

But when i load yaml resources with `kubernetes-client:5.2.1` library from Java code, there is an Exception occurs:

```java
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:53)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal(Serialization.java:140)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal(Serialization.java:101)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.<init>(NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.java:272)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.<init>(NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.java:252)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient$1.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:175)
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.load(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:175)
  at app.test.main(test.java:38)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No resource type found for:kafka.strimzi.io/v1#Kafka
 at [Source: (String)"{"apiVersion":"kafka.strimzi.io/v1","kind":"Kafka","metadata":{"name":"my-cluster"},"spec":{"kafka":{"replicas":1,"listeners":[{"name":"plain","port":9092,"type":"internal","tls":false},{"name":"tls","port":9093,"type":"internal","tls":true,"authentication":{"type":"tls"}},{"name":"external","port":9094,"type":"nodeport","tls":false}],"storage":{"type":"jbod","volumes":[{"id":0,"type":"persistent-claim","size":"1Gi","deleteClaim":false}]},"config":{"offsets.topic.replication.factor":1,"transacti"[truncated 226 chars]; line: 1, column: 726]
```

Problem occurs when i load this file: [yaml config](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/master/examples/kafka/kafka-ephemeral.yaml).

I load resource like:

```java
 KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
InputStream is = ...;
client.load(is).inNamespace("my_namespace").createOrReplace();
```

Please help me!

P.S: And sorry for my English.

Comment: Hello, `Kafka` is a CustomResource. Please have a look at Fabric8 Kubernetes Client CustomResource API: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#customresource-typeless-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from Fabric8 team. `Kafka` is a Custom Resource which means it's model is not registered in KubernetesClient so this is the reason why you're facing `No resource type found for:kafka.strimzi.io/v1#Kafka` error from KubenetesClient. KubernetesClient provides two methods for dealing with Custom Resources:

1. Typeless API - Usage of CustomResources as raw Hashmaps
2. Typed API    - Provide POJOs for CustomResource types

I'll provide examples of using both APIs to load your Kafka yaml fragment.

**Typeless API:**

For Typeless API you would need to provide a `CustomResourceDefinitionContext`, an object with details of CustomResource group, version, kind, plural etc. Here is how it would look like:
[KafkaLoadTypeless.java](https://github.com/rohanKanojia/stackoverflow-code/blob/master/java-posts/src/main/java/in/rohaan/KafkaLoadTypeles.java)

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    CustomResourceDefinitionContext context = new CustomResourceDefinitionContext.Builder()
            .withScope("Namespaced")
            .withVersion("v1beta2")
            .withGroup("kafka.strimzi.io")
            .withPlural("kafkas")
            .build();

    InputStream is = KafkaLoadTypeles.class.getResourceAsStream("/test-kafka.yml");

    Map<String, Object> createdKafka = client.customResource(context).inNamespace("default").createOrReplace(is);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Typed API:**

For typed API, you would need to provide types for `Kafka` resource. You can find these types in Strimzi API dependency. I had to add this dependency in my project in order to use `Kafka` classes:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.strimzi</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

After adding this, I was able to use Typed API like this:
[KafkaLoadTyped.java](https://github.com/rohanKanojia/stackoverflow-code/blob/master/java-posts/src/main/java/in/rohaan/KafkaLoadTyped.java)

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
    MixedOperation<Kafka, KafkaList, Resource<Kafka>> kafkaClient = client.customResources(Kafka.class, KafkaList.class);

    InputStream is = KafkaLoadTyped.class.getResourceAsStream("/test-kafka.yml");
    Kafka myClusterkafka = kafkaClient.load(is).get();
    kafkaClient.inNamespace("default").createOrReplace(myClusterkafka);
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanx!

Comment: Np, Happy to help :-) !